# Good ways to create a Scala class whose Type parameter depends on composing object Type

Tags: scala

I'm honing up my scala skills and I'm writing a few graph ing algorithms. I have an API representation for graph which is something like this

```
trait GraphLike[T]
{
  val vertices: Map[ T, VertexLike[T] ] 
  def addVertex( t: T ): GraphLike[T]
  def addEdge( a:T, b:T ): GraphLike[T]
  def getAdjacencyList( a: T ): List[T]
  def getVertex( a: T ): VertexLike[T]
  ...
}
```

I then have another class:

```
class DepthFirstSearch[ T ]( val graph: GraphLike[T], val sourceVertex: T )
{
  ...
}
```

Currently I found that I have to do this to create an instance of the DepthFirstSearch class

```
val dfs = new DepthFirstSearch[Integer]( new UnDirGraph[Integer](/*some params*/), 1 )
```

where `UnDirGraph` is a `GraphLike` sub-class

I have to specify the type parameter in `new DepthFirstSearch[Integer]`. Is there a way that Type checker can infer this from the graph parameter provided. I found that I couldn't
do something like this

```
val dfs = new DepthFirstSearch( new UnDirGraph[Integer](/*some params*/), 1 )
```

Currently the above fails... Is there a way something like the above can be done?

EDIT: So the error message I get is 
    type mismatch;  found   : com.KGraph.GraphLike[Integer]
    required: com.KGraph.GraphLike[Any] 
    Note: Integer <: Any, but trait GraphLike is invariant
    in type T. You may wish to define T as +T instead. (SLS 4.5)

this is how I try to create

```
val graph = Graphing.createUndiGraphFromFile( 
            new File("/Volumes/Data/Users/kartik/ScalaSpace/Graph/tinyG.txt" ) )
val dfs = new DepthFirstSearch( graph, 0 )
```

where `crateUndiGraphFromFile` returns a GraphLike[Integer]

Comment: A little more info would be nice. For example what is the error message?

Comment: It infers the type / enforces consistent binding of `T`, but it does not automatically find and invoke a constructor. You can do that usng reflection. You have to get a `ClassTag` (the compiler will do that for you if you ask) and then get enmeshed in reflection. And since you need something other than the default (no-arg) constructor, it's rather more inovled that it would be for the default construtor. I know Java reflection can be used for this sort of thing (I've done it), but I'm unfamiliar with the 2.10 Scala reflection capbilities in this area. There's a chance it's less ugly that way.

Comment: @Kartik Aiyer: No time for a proper answer right now, but you should be aware that `Integer` refers to `java.lang.Integer` rather than the primitive `scala.Int`. Changing `Integer` to `Int` is likely to fix your problem (I tried quickly in the repl, and had a variance error with `Integer`, but none with `Int`). @Randall Schulz: I think you misunderstood the question, somehow.

Comment: To expand, the literal `1` is a `scala.Int`, not a `java.lang.Integer`.  Thus, the *common* type, and only applicable inference for `T`, is `Any`.  But if `T` resolves to `Any`, that means that you would be assigning an `UnDirGraph[Int]` to a `GraphLike[Any]` which is not allowed, as `T` is not covariant (it is *invariant*).  Hence the suggestion from the compiler about using `+T` instead of `T`.  The really interesting part to me is that once you add `[Integer]` it works, which suggests that `1` can be automatically converted to a `java.lang.Integer` when forced, something I didn't know yet.

Comment: @MarkPeters `1` being converted to `java.lang.Integer` is common boxing. In Scala, `Predef.int2Integer` takes care of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Credits to @Régis Jean-Gilles and @Mark Peters

Common super-type of `Integer` and `1` (of type `Int`) is `Any`. So when writing this:

```
val dfs = new DepthFirstSearch( new UnDirGraph[Integer](/*some params*/), 1 )
```

The type inference gives you

```
val dfs = new DepthFirstSearch[Any]( new UnDirGraph[Integer](/*some params*/), 1 )
```

But now, we need

```
new UnDirGraph[Integer](/*some params*/) <: UniDirGraph[Any]
```

which is not the case as `UnDirGraph` is invariant.

If you write:

```
val dfs = new DepthFirstSearch[Integer]( new UnDirGraph[Integer](/*some params*/), 1 )
```

Scala will implicitly convert the `1` to an `Integer` and then everything is fine.

As @Régis Jean-Gilles points out, the following will work:

```
val dfs = new DepthFirstSearch( new UnDirGraph[Int](/*some params*/), 1 )
```